# How can I get the timeslider using Cartojs and Torquejs

Tags: carto, torque

I want to build the timesilder on my webpage.The timeslider on Carto Builder is nice for me.Now I can get the first img' timeslider, But I want the second one and don't know how to achieve it.What library or ui should I need?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately that's not doable at this moment with any official CARTO tools directly.

The new CARTO.js library provides a [Time Series](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/reference/#cartodataviewtimeseries) data view ([example](https://carto.com/developers/carto-js/examples/#example-time-series-widget)), which may be the base to code a widget using any charting JS library out there, but for the animated points map (Torque) is not yet ported to the new library version.

You may want to try to combine both versions of the library to get the animated map from cartodb.js `v3` and the widget on top of `v4` dataview, but no idea how that would look like.

Comment: Yeah,I see now.I will try it and find that d3 is used to build the time-slider by reading the source code[http://bbvatourism.vizzuality.com/](http://bbvatourism.vizzuality.com/).
Thank you very much~

Comment: please mark the answer as valid so we keep stats correct :-)